# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: How to i fix it?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

Error All

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.Label.setText(String)" because "this.as" is null
    at com.gluonhq.samples.comments.views.ProfilePresenter.initData(ProfilePresenter.java:51)
    at com.gluonhq.samples.comments.views.CommentsPresenter.lambda$initialize$3(CommentsPresenter.java:104)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@19/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@19/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3599)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3903)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1887)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2620)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@19/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
```

ProfilePresenter.java
Here is my fxml controller and I'm fetching the information from the commentPresenter

```
package com.gluonhq.samples.comments.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ListTile;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.samples.comments.model.Comment;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class ProfilePresenter  {





@FXML
protected View profile;
@FXML
private Label as;

@FXML
private ImageView jembatan;

@FXML
private Button back;

@FXML
private Label bridge;


    private String data;

    public void initData(Comment comment){
        var listSel = comment;


        String value = listSel.getAuthor();
        as.setText(value);
    }

    public  void setData(String name) {
       data = name;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        Image img = new Image("jembatan_1.jpeg");
        jembatan.setImage(img);


        profile.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = AppManager.getInstance().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e ->
                        AppViewManager.COMMENTS_VIEW.switchView()));
                appBar.setTitleText("Brigde Profile");
            }
        });

    }

    public void updateData(String content) {
        bridge.setText(content);
    }



}
```

CommentPresenter.java
Here is my fxml controller and I'm fetching the information from the commentPresenter

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2016, 2021, Gluon
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 * documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *     * Neither the name of Gluon, any associated website, nor the
 * names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 * derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL GLUON BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
package com.gluonhq.samples.comments.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.FloatingActionButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.samples.comments.cloud.Service;
import com.gluonhq.samples.comments.model.Comment;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.IOException;



public class CommentsPresenter{

    @Inject 
    protected Service service;



    @FXML
    protected View comments;

    @FXML
    protected ListView<Comment> commentsList;

    public void initialize() {
        comments.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = AppManager.getInstance().getAppBar();
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e ->
                        AppManager.getInstance().getDrawer().open()));
                appBar.setTitleText("List Bridge");
            }
        });



        commentsList.setCellFactory(p -> new CommentListCell());
        commentsList.setPlaceholder(new Label("There are no comments"));
        commentsList.getItems().add(new Comment("1","Jembatan Merah", "Palembang Indonesia"));
        



        commentsList.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {

            var myIndex = commentsList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            var test = commentsList.getItems().get(myIndex);

            ProfilePresenter profilePresenter = new ProfilePresenter();

            profilePresenter.initData(commentsList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            AppViewManager.PROFILE_VIEW.switchView();

        });



        service.retrieveComments();
    }




}
```

I conveyed information from the Comment Presenter to the Presenter Profile and then I wanted to setText my label but instead there was an error like the one above, but when it was printed in the console the data appeared. How to Fix It

Comment: I'm not familiar with gluon mobile or gluon fx, but your `CommentsPresenter` and `ProfilePresenter` look like controller classes associated with FXML files. The `@FXML` annotation means the field will be initialized *in the controller object created by the `FXMLLoader`* when the corresponding FXML file is loaded. In your code you just do `ProfilePresenter profilePresenter = new ProfilePresenter();`, and then call `initData()` on that object you created. Why would you expect `as` to be non-null in `profilePresenter`?

Comment: You are using `awt` imports in the `ProfilePresenter`.